# Why put a telescope on moon?

Tags: the-moon, telescope

According to [this](http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/slideshows/science-technology/isro-might-put-a-telescope-on-the-moon/detailed-understanding-of-the-universe/slideshow/54895963.cms) report:

> As a follow-on mission to India's first space X-ray observatory, ASTROSAT, ISRO is planning to set up a telescope on moon.ISRO chairman A S Kiran Kumar said that the telescope can have lot of advantages as there were no atmosphere or atmospheric effects associated with it.

What advantages would this telescope have over the present space based telescopes in orbit around the Earth or the Sun?

Comment: Is your question answered [here](http://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14866/would-a-lunar-telescope-provide-a-significant-improvement-over-terrestrial-based)?

Comment: Yes it certainly did! I would not have posted it if I found this question. Thanks! Can I close this question myself or should it be done by others?